# Marijuana in car ignites and the driver gets high during a car chase

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm not sure where else on the internet to ask this and I've tried looking extensively myself.

Many years ago when I was much younger I saw a movie on TV (SBS Australia if that helps anyone) that I only caught the end of and its lodged its self like a splinter in my mind ever since. This was many years ago (maybe 5+?) so its not a recent movie.

It was a foreign film from what i remember, but i don't know what language.

I remember the following final sequence of events (which is all I saw)

- someone gets shot and its quite bloody (a shotgun perhaps?)
- someone acquires an insane amount of marijuana and stuffs it all into a tiny little box car
- the person in the box car is chased by people shooting at them and for some reason being shot at makes the marijuana ignite and fills the car cabin smoke
- the driver of the car is now extremely high and stumbles out of the car onto the side of the road and is (i think) in the desert surrounded by cacti.
- he see's the New Zealand All Blacks rugby team staring him down who then do the 'haka' and he runs off screaming into the distance as the credits roll.

I got a copy of the New Zealand movie 'Scarfies', however it's not the right movie unfortunately.

Comment: I don't remember all the details, but french movie [La Beuze](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0343426/reviews?ref_=tt_urv) comes to mind. As far as I remember, the whole car was made of marijuana

Comment: @defaultlocale YES YES YES YES YES YES YES!!! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YseTVVWD9YM THAT IS EXACTLY IT!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's such a scene with police officer at the end of french movie [La Beuze](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0343426/reviews?ref_=tt_urv). In the movie the whole car was made of marijuana.